# Laravel - How to pluck field from nested relations

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to pluck field from nested relations.

My class structure is:

```
User      hasMany       GroupUser
GroupUser belongsTo     Group
Group     belongsToMany Promotion
```

So this way I can get fine get Promotions from an User

```
$user->groupUsers()->with('group')->with('group.promotions')->get();

{
  "id": 4,
  ....
  "promotions": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "group_id": 11,
      "user_id": 4,
      ...
      "group": {
        "id": 11,
        ...
        "promotions": [
          {
            "id": 8,
            "title": "Lavagem Mensal 1 unid.",
            "const": "LAVAGEM_MENSAL1_UNID",
            "pivot": {
              "group_id": 11,
              "promotion_id": 8
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So what I need is to get a pluck list of `Promotions.const`.

Tried this way but it returns `[null]`

```
$user->groupUsers()->with('group')->with('group.promotions')->get()->pluck('group.promotions.const');
```

UPDATE: Now this way I close to achieve it.

```
$user->groupUsers()->with('group')->with('group.promotions')->get()->pluck('group.promotions.*.const');

"promotions": [
  [
    "BRF_LAVAGEM_MENSAL_1_UNID"
  ]
]
```

Just need to flat this array.

Comment: try `$user->groupUsers()->with('group')->with('group.promotions')->get()->value('group.promotions.const');`

Comment: @MathiasHillmann it returns `Collection::value does not exist`

Comment: Sidenote (it doesn't fix your issue) `->with('group')->with('group.promotions')` is redundant; if you simply do `->with('group.promotions')`, it'll automatically include `group` and `promotions` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$user->groupUsers()
    ->with('group.promotions')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('group.promotions.*.const')
    ->collapse();
```